# how to iterate one time over a loop each time call a function?

Tags: c++, loops, iteration, static-variables

I have loop and want to iterate one time each time I call the function.
This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void iter(int max_i, int max_j){

        static int i = 0;
        static int j = 0;
        for (; i< max_i; i++ ){
                for(; i<max_j; j++){
                        std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
                        return;
                }
        }
}


int main(){

        iter(4,4);
        iter(4,4);
        iter(4,4);
        return 0;

}
```

But the result shows that each time the function is called it starts from zero.

```sh
amirreza@time:/tmp$ g++ iterate.cpp 
amirreza@time:/tmp$ ./a.out 
0 0
0 0
0 0
```

Comment: You return before incrementing, so `i` and `j` never change.

Comment: `return;` ??? What was the plan there? If it was anything *other* than a hard stop-the-function-and-return-to-caller-now, you missed the mark. Therefore, *"each time the function is called it starts from zero"* is more accurate to say "each time the function is called neither `i` nor `j` are ever changed."

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code, and your description "*I have loop and want to iterate one time ...*" That's not really what loops are for. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @dxiv if I change `i++` to `++i` does it solve?

Comment: Do you know what that `return;` is doing?

Comment: It looks like you want to have something like coroutines. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines if you want to do a step of your for loop by every call. It is quite unclear what you are asking...

Comment: @WhozCraig I return to stop and exit function

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi No, it won't get executed either way because of the `return`. What is it exactly that you are trying to achieve, and what output do you expect?

Comment: I think I understand. You want it to behave like a loop, but only once per call. I.e. the first call i=0,j=0. Second i=0,j=1, etc. When j reaches max_j it resets and i is incremented, etc. Out of curiosity, what do you want to transpire when i and j actuall both reach their limits? Just become a no-op from then on?

Comment: @dxiv I have loop over some data, I want the function return the next item each time I call it, but in this sample code here the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @WhozCraig exactly!

Comment: That is exactly what coroutines provide

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi yeah, this sounds like an XY problem. you want loop control in the caller, but functional operation in the function. I.e. you loops should be in `main` and the function should just take the "current" `i` and `j` as arguments.

Comment: @Klaus pretend for a moment some of us are plagued with toolchains that aren't on the C++20 standard (and that isn't negotiable). Then... what.?

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi You could replace the test condition with `i++ < max_i` (and drop the other `i++`) which would give you a sequential iteration (and you could adjust that to make it 0-based instead of 1-based). But it would still be an odd way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it should be

```
void iter(int max_i, int max_j){
    static int i = 0;
    static int j = 0;

    if (i < max_i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
        if (++j >= max_j) {
            ++i;
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f00026df69fb0868)

Better to have all those variables in class to avoid static which might be problematic. Something like:

```
truct IterData
{
    const int max_i;
    const int max_j;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
};

bool iter(IterData& data){
    std::cout << data.i << " " << data.j << std::endl;
    if (++data.j >= data.max_j) {
        ++data.i;
        data.j = 0;
    }
    return data.i < data.max_i;
}

int main()
{
    IterData data{4, 4};

    while (iter(data));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8dc095b80f30d48)

C++20 has co-routine to allow to write the loop most naturally.